# How do I loop through nested arrays in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, for-loop

I'm creating a grid using a 2-d array and i want to put different values in it 
I have tried:

```
grid =(Array.new(10,Array.new(10," ") ))
for row in rand(1..9)
     for column in rand(1..9)
        grid[row][column] == 'a'
```

Comment: Use `rand(1..9).each { |row| ... }`; no one uses `for` in Ruby except those unfamiliar with it :-)

Comment: try printing `p rand(1..9)`, you will see that it doesn't give you an array, but a random integer within that range. You cannot loop over integers. They also don't have "each" method. They are not enumerables.

Comment: You are creating grid incorrectly. After executing the first line, run `grid[0][0]='X'; p grid` and you'll see what I mean. It's defined correctly in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
grid = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10, "") }
```

otherwise you'll get the same array repeated 10 times, which is presumably not what you want.

I am not sure what you want to do with your iterations. Do note that Ruby arrays are 0-indexed, so a 10-element array will have an index in `0...9`. Also note that iteration over an array is usually done with `each`, as Carpetsmoker notes in comments:

```
grid.each do |row|
  row.each_index do |index|
    row[index] = "abcde"[rand(5)]
  end
end
```

EDIT: Thanks Cary!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. If you want to put the letter 'a' at `n` random locations in `grid`, you could do this:

```
def salt(grid, obj, n)
  m = grid.size
  locs = (0...m*m).to_a.sample(n)
  locs.each do |l|
    row, col = l.divmod(m)
    grid[row][col] = obj
  end
end

grid = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10, ' ') }

salt(grid,'a',30)
grid
  #=> [[" ", "a", " ", " ", "a", "a", "a", " ", " ", " "],
  #    ["a", "a", " ", "a", "a", " ", " ", "a", " ", " "],
  #    [" ", "a", " ", " ", "a", " ", " ", " ", "a", " "],
  #    [" ", " ", " ", "a", " ", " ", "a", " ", " ", "a"],
  #    [" ", " ", " ", "a", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  #    [" ", " ", "a", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  #    ["a", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "a", " ", " ", "a"],
  #    [" ", " ", "a", " ", " ", "a", " ", "a", " ", " "],
  #    [" ", "a", " ", " ", "a", " ", " ", " ", "a", "a"],
  #    [" ", " ", "a", "a", "a", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]
```

You could instead write:

```
locs =  n.times.map { rand(m*m) }
```

but that will likely result in some duplicates, in which case fewer than `n` cells will be filled with `"a"`'s. For example, when I computed `locs` that way for `n=30` I found:

```
locs.uniq.size
  #=> 27
```